# How to enable cache for a method inside dynamic bean

Tags: caching, spring-boot, guava

I am creating a dynamic bean using "AutowireCapableBeanFactory" as follows

**RegisterFoo.java**

```
@Configuration
public class registerFoo {
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext appcontext;

    AutowireCapableBeanFactory bf;

    @PostConstruct
    public void registerFoo() {
        bf = appContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        RootBeanDefinition def = new RootBeanDefinition(Foo.class);
        ((DefaultListableBeanFactory)bf).registerBean("foo", def);
    }
}
```

**RegisterBar.java**

```
@Configuration
public class registerBar {
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext appcontext;

    AutowireCapableBeanFactory bf;

    @PostConstruct
    public void registerFoo() {
        bf = appContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        RootBeanDefinition def = new RootBeanDefinition(Bar.class);
         Foo foo = (Foo) appContext.getBean("foo");
        ConstructorArgumentValues cav = new ConstructorArgumentValues();
        cav.add(0, foo.getValue());
        def.setArgumentValues(cav);
        ((DefaultListableBeanFactory)bf).registerBean("bar", def);
    }
}
```

Foo.class

```
public class Foo {
    @Cacheable
    public String getValue() {
        // return value
    }
}
```

The method getValue() executes its body every time. Spring doesn't cache the value as expected. Any suggestions?

Comment: Any inputs here really appreciated.

Comment: Do you have other places in your application where the cache works? Except of the dynamic bean?

Comment: @Patrick - Yes, it works for normal beans. i.e the beans created using ```@Bean``` annotation.

Comment: How did you enable the caching annotations? There's no @EnableCaching on the posted configuration classes.

Comment: @thirstycrow We have ```@EnableCaching``` in our ```@SpringBootApplication``` class

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that when spring register a bean with annotation, it is then post-processed by a bean post processor that will manage @Cacheable

When you register it manually, the post-processing might not get done.

Can't verify it for the moment, but that's where I'll look first.

Hope this help.